# Pip Global Install Not Working

Tags: python, pip, package, installation, global

I followed [this guide](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) to setting up a Python environment and I'm having trouble with the part where you set up a function to bypass the virtual environment requirement. Basically, I want gpip install to work without a virtual environment. Also open to other methods of accomplishing this.

This is my pip.conf file:

```
[install]
require-virtualenv = true

[uninstall]
require-virtualenv = true
```

This is my .bash_profile file:

```
1 # Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
2 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
3 # Load .bashrc if it exists
4 test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

This is my .bashrc file:

```
1 gpip(){
2         PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
3 }
```

I've also tried

```
1 gpip(){
2         PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
3 }
```

I still get

```
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

when I type in

```
gpip install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the following

```
gpip(){
        PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
}
```

to

```
gpip(){
        PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="false" pip3 "$@"
}
```